# How can I search an HTML website for a keyword and paste that link in the search bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-webbrowser

I am trying to make a textbox that extracts a word into a keyword in chrome. When i press a button the keyword in the textbox gets implemented into chrome and if that keyword is found, it then goes into that hyperlink.

The code is so far:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import webbrowser

root = Tk()

url = 'https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/'

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

def OpenUrl():
    webbrowser.open_new(url)

button = Button(frame, text="Start", command=OpenUrl)

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What do you mean by 'extracts a word into a keyword in chrome'? Which hyperlink are you talking about? Where does the word come from? Do you already tried some code? If so, please add it to your question.

Comment: I have made a textbox that i can write in, and i have a button. When i press the button, i want the text in the textbox to be implemented into chrome as a keyword. I am trying to make a bot for https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/, written in python. And i want a keyword function that searches for a specific clothing piece.

Comment: @HugoSigurdson  when adding detail to your question, add it to the *body* of the question; comments aren't the correct place, and comments are much more limited in length and formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.
For me it works when I entered 'python'.

```
from tkinter import *
import webbrowser

def google(event):

    address = "http://www.google.com/#q="
    word = input("What do you want to search for? ")
    search = address + word
    webbrowser.open_new(search)


root = Tk()
textbox = Entry(root)
button = Button(root, text="Click")
button.bind("<Button-1>", google)
textbox.pack()
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

For the next time, please provide your code even if it is only the creation of your tkinter widgets.

***** Edit *****

For html searching, try to use the following code:

```
def checkForWord():
    r = requests.get("http://example.com/somepage.html")
    return "myWord" in r.text
```

If the html lookup works, incorporate both parts and replace the **word** variable with the **checkForWord** function.

Comment: It crashes for me everytime i try and write something. And it does not search for a specific word in an html webpage.

Comment: This is what i have written, https://pastebin.com/ebZxMGAk. Some of it is in Swedish.

Comment: No, it does not search for a word on a website. It takes a word you enter in your editor and searches the word in google. Did you try my code and it crashes for you?

Comment: But i want a textbox that searches for a specific word on https://shop.palaceskateboards.com/, then enters that link containing that word.

Comment: It still crashes for me. And it now works somewhat, but i want it to search inside the element of the html doc.

Comment: And i have to paste what i want to search for in cmd now. It does not search when i put the keyword in the box and press the button.

Comment: Can you please provide an update version of your code?

Comment: Do you have access to the html doc or database to look there directly?

Comment: I am very new to python as you notice. No i dont. But i might be able to specify the item”keyword” via Inspect Element on chrome? Might not even work in python?